# Unique Value For Each Button

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have two php pages. The first page queries a database and places some data into a form
The second page, grabs the data submited from the previous page and displays the data.

THE ISSUE:
On the second page, the information is displayed in a table. At the end of each row, there is a "information" button that allows the user to click and see more details related to the data in that particular column. For some reason, the information button for every record in the table is holding the value of the first record returned in the database query. In other words no matter what button I click on in the table, it always relates to the first record returned in the query.

I'm hoping someone can help me find a solution to linking each "information" button to each unique record. In other words If I click the info button in row one, it will display the data for the record related to row 1...etc. Here's my code.

PAGE 1

```
<?php

$query = mysql_query ("SELECT  * from cust_data group by cabinet_number ORDER by cabinet_number ASC");

WHILE ($rows = @mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

    if (($rows['account_number']=="") &&
        ($rows['customer_first_name']=="") &&
        ($rows['customer_last_name']=="") &&
        ($rows['company_name']=="")) {

        echo '<form method="GET" action="cabinet_result_page.php">
                <input type="hidden" value="'.$rows['cabinet_number'].'" name="cabinet_number">
                <input type="hidden" value="'.$rows['company_name'].'" name="company_name">
                <img src="images/bulletpoint_green.png">
                <input type="submit" value="'.$rows['cabinet_number'].'" name="'.$rows['cabinet_number'].'" id="submit">
              </form>';

    } else if ($rows['cabinet_number']!=="") {

        echo '<form method="GET" action="cabinet_result_page.php">
                      <input type="hidden" value="'.$rows['cabinet_number'].'" name="cabinet_number">
                      <input type="hidden" value="'.$rows['company_name'].'" name="company_name">
                      <img src="images/bulletpoint_red.png">
                      <input type="submit" value="'.$rows['cabinet_number'].'" name="'.$rows['company_name'].'" id="submit">
              </form>';
    }
  }
}
```

PAGE 2: 
GRABS THE DATA IN PAGE ONE AND PLACES IT IN A TABLE.  WHEN THE 'INFO' BUTTON IS CLICKED, MORE INFORMATION IS DISPLAYED IN A JQUERY POPUP

```
db_connect();

$cabinet_number = $_GET['cabinet_number'];
$company_name = $_GET['company_name'];
$query = @mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM cust_data WHERE cabinet_number = '$cabinet_number' ");

WHILE ($rows = @mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

    echo'<tr>
            <td><font size="4">'; echo $rows['account_number']; echo'</font></td>
            <td><font size="4">'; echo $rows['customer_first_name']; echo '</font></td>
            <td><font size="4">'; echo $rows['customer_last_name']; echo '</font></td>
            <td><font size="4">'; echo $rows['company_name']; echo '</font></td>
            <td><font size="4">'; echo $rows['cabinet_number']; echo'</font></td>
            <td><font size="4">'; echo $rows['key_tag_number']; echo'</font></td>';

    if ($rows['switch_and_port1'] =="") {

        echo '';

    } else if ($rows['switch_and_port1'] !== "") {

        echo '<td><font size="4">';
        echo '<input type = "image" src= "images/view_details.png" height="16" width="16" class="my_modal_open">', '</font></td>';

    }

    {
        echo '<td><font size="4">'; echo '<input type = "image" src= "images/view_details.png" height="16" width="16" class="my_modal_open">', '</font></td>';
    }

    echo '</tr>';
    echo '<div  class="well" style="display:none;margin:1em;" class="my_modal">';
    echo '<img src="images/hdc_logo_transparent.png"><br>';
    echo '<div style="height:23px; width:100%; background-color:black"> <h4><font color="#FFFFFF">','&nbsp; ', 'Cabinet: ', $id, '</font></h4></div>';
    echo '<p>';
    echo '<br>';
    echo '<img src="images/bulletpoint_orange.png">';
    echo 'Power: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;', $rows['power_circuit'];
    echo '<br>';
    echo'<img src="images/bulletpoint_orange.png">';
    echo 'Sw/Po: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;', $rows['switch_and_port1'];

    if ($rows['switch_and_port2'] =="") {

        echo '';

    } else if ($rows['switch_and_port2'] !== "") {
        echo '<br>';
        echo '<img src="images/bulletpoint_orange.png">';
        echo 'Sw/Po: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;', $rows['switch_and_port2'];
    }

    if ($rows['switch_and_port3'] =="") {

        echo '';

    } else if ($rows['switch_and_port3'] !== "") {

        echo '<br>';
        echo '<img src="images/bulletpoint_orange.png">';
        echo 'Sw/Po: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;', $rows['switch_and_port3'];
    }

    if ($rows['switch_and_port4'] =="") {

        echo '';

    } else if ($rows['switch_and_port4'] !== "") {

        echo '<br>';
        echo '<img src="images/bulletpoint_orange.png">';
        echo 'Sw/Po: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;', $rows['switch_and_port4'];
    }

    echo '</p>';
    echo'</div></form>';

}
echo'<script>
                $(document).ready(function() {
                $(".my_modal_open").click(function(){
                $(this).closest("tr").next(".my_modal").popup({"autoopen": true});
                });
                });
                });
                </script>
                </body>
                </html>';
}
```

Comment: where in all your code is the information button? can you reduce your code sample to just the relevant pieces? also the `<font>` tag is deprecated, use proper CSS

Comment: Did you ever heard about identation?

Comment: A suggestion.  I see that you are using a company name as a search query to grab more specific data.  I **STRONGLY** recommend against that.  You should use an ID system.  Whether you are using an Auto Increment field or some random number, you should be querying with an integer because it is a lot faster, more efficient, and a lot cleaner.  It's just good database design.

Comment: @Kola - Sorry about that. I updated the code and reduced it

Comment: Good catch user2754433. I'll look into modifying that part of it.

Comment: I have 3 strands of hair left. Any more ideas? Hurry before i lose them!

Comment: where's the moadal? where do you set it's contents and where do you open it?

Comment: You have a lot of syntax error... I edited but not correct your error`s....

Comment: Where do you see syntax errors? I'm running this on my dev server live and it runs just fine. The only issue I"m having is getting the more details button to load the correct data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are setting the same id attribute to all the modals (which is invalid HTML markup) and expecting the click handler on the button to figure out which one to open.

**UPADTE**

Another issue with your markup is that you can't have `<div>`s as siblings of a table row, it will produce unexpected results as browsers will attempt to fix the markup and rearrange the elements, you could place the divs inside a td or use a second loop to build them.

Now I also did some digging in your popup plugin and I must say it's not very well implemented, I would recommend you look for another one. That being said I did manage to get it working, here's what you need to do:

1. Set an unique id for each of the modal divs, if you have some sort of id in your database data you can use that, if not then you can set up a counter variable inside the loop:

   ```
   echo '<div class="well" id="my_modal'.$rows['id'].'">';
   ```
2. Use the same id as the class for the button that should open the modal but add "_open" as a suffix:

   ```
   echo '<input type = "image" src="images/view_details.png" height="16" width="16" class="my_modal'.rows['id'].'_open">
   ```
3. You can now initialize the popup plugin on your divs and it will automatically assign the open action to the corresponding button:

   ```
   echo'<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("[id^=\'my_modal\']").each(function () {
                $(this).popup();
            });
        });
        </script>';
   ```

That should fix the modal problem, here's a **[working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/APKbC/10/)**.

Now I also have a couple observations about your code:

1. You should avoid the use of inline styles and as I mentioned earlier the `<font>` tag should be replaced for proper CSS, I would also suggest using CSS padding/margin to add space between words instead of `&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;`
2. This type of code:

   ```
   if ($rows['switch_and_port1'] =="") {
       echo '';
   } else if ($rows['switch_and_port1'] !== "") {
       echo 'SOME CONTENT';
   }
   ```

   can be optimized to just:

   ```
   if ($rows['switch_and_port1'] !== "") {
       echo 'SOME CONTENT';
   }
   ```

   echoing an empty string produces no output whatsoever and there's no need for an elseif

Comment: Thanks for your reply Koala. I updated the div part to reference modal as a class. I also up DOM traversal methods and it broke the linking for the more details button. When I click on the button now, nothing happens. What am I missing here? The original code above has been updated to reflect my updates.

Comment: @user2754433 you have an extra `});` at the end, if it's a typo here then maybe you can set up a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with a sample of your markup and the jquery code to help diagnose the issue

Comment: I have never used fiddle. In fact this is my first time attemtping to work with it. I'm not 100% sure i even understand what it is, however i have setup a sample mock up - http://jsfiddle.net/APKbC/  . Hopefully this helps.

Comment: @user2754433 you can't use PHP in a fiddle, copy the generated markup from the page source and use that (don't include `<html>` or `<body>` tags, just content), also you can add the jquery library from the "frameworks & extension" section on the left and use the external resources panel to add the plugin, you'll need an online hosted URL

Comment: Wow, this jfiddle site is pretty useful and powerful. Anyways, I updated the code on the page http://jsfiddle.net/APKbC/2/. See if this is a little more useful.

Comment: @user2754433 I can't find any modal links or divs in the html, can you update this fiddle with some sample content from your second page http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/APKbC/7/

Comment: Actually, you are looking at the second page. Sort of. Do you have an email address? I will create a web link for you see the functionality in a web browser. If that will be of more help.

Comment: Too add to my previous comment, the second page is just a jquery popup with data. It loads from the same page.

Comment: Ok, so I've updated according to your updates. The use of the unique id sounds logical. I am using auto-incremented ids in the database, so I was able to plug that call in. For some reason the button is still inactive. It does nothing when clicked. I have a feeling there might be a small syntax error that my PHP IDE isn't catching. I couldn't "cleanly" post my update here, so look here. If you don't mind, see if you can find a syntax error in the java. Something still isnt right - http://jsfiddle.net/abYTv/

Comment: Ok, I finally got the buttons to do something thanks to your help. PHP did not like the single quotes for the java execution part at the end. However, changing this to double quotes broke the functionality of the button. Changing this back to single quotes and escaping the single quotes with "\" resolved that part of it. Now that the buttons are working, I still see the issue with them not pulling the right data for each unique record. I've updated http://jsfiddle.net/abYTv/1/ to reference the escape quotes.

Comment: YES! YES! YES! I think you got it koala. I had to escape a couple quotes in the java and I think it is now working as expected. My entire weekend has been dedicated to trying to resolve this ONE issue. Man you have REALLY REALLY REALLY been of GREAT help. I thank you for your time and HUGE efforts. Do you have a paypal donate link or something? I don't mind sending you a little something for your time and help. I'm going to play around with this a bit more and hopefully it's all smooth sailing from here. Thank again my friend!

Comment: @user2754433 glad to hear everything is working now, I'm sorry about the confusion with the quotes, I just copied the jquery code from the fiddle but forgot to adjust it so you could place it inside the PHP echo statement, and thanks but there's no need for a donation, though I would appreciate it if you could upvote/accept this answer, there's a green check mark below the voting arrows that you can click to accept it. Thanks and good luck with your project!